# Divide N elements among M buckets of different sizes proportionally to bucket sizes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have N objects, and I want to divide them across M buckets of different sizes. The larger the bucket, the more objects it should receive.

I've currently solved the problem as follows, but it looks overkill to me. I'm implementing the problem with python/numpy/scipy right now, and this code will be executed very often in my compute-intensive scientific application.

First, I generate a discrete probability distribution:

```
bucket_sizes = numpy.array([10., 7., 3., 20.])
bucket_ratios = bucket_sizes / bucket_sizes.sum()
dist = scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(range(bucket_sizes.size), bucket_ratios))
```

Then, I generate N samples:

```
sample = dist.rcv(size=N)
```

Finally, I count the occurrences of each bucket id in the sample

```
bucket_id, counts = numpy.unique(sample, return_counts=True)
```

I now have the number of elements to be put in each bucket inside of `counts`.

While this works, I have the feeling i should be able to do this faster without generating list of ids to then count (and sort).

Ideas?

**EDIT**

For reference, I have found a corresponding but much faster pure-numpy solution.

```
_, counts = numpy.unique(numpy.random.choice(N, bucket_ratios), return_counts=True)
```

Comment: Is the randomness part of the requirement?  Or, for example, if there are 100 objects and just two buckets of equal size, would a method that always returns exactly [50, 50] work?

Comment: In your example yes. The question is how to manage N=7 with 10 buckets of equal size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the question if you want a *random* assignment, and the "bucket sizes" establish the relative probabilities of the assignment to a bucket.  Such a random distribution is known as the [`multinomial distribution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).  You can draw samples from a multinomial distribution using [`numpy.random.multinomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html).  For example:

```
In [32]: bucket_sizes
Out[32]: array([10,  7,  3, 20])

In [33]: N
Out[33]: 100

In [34]: p = bucket_sizes / float(bucket_sizes.sum())

In [35]: p
Out[35]: array([ 0.25 ,  0.175,  0.075,  0.5  ])

In [36]: np.random.multinomial(N, p)
Out[36]: array([25, 24,  4, 47])

In [37]: np.random.multinomial(N, p)
Out[37]: array([32, 15,  8, 45])
```

Comment: Random is indeed what I need and to a certain extent what is necessary. How to manage fairly N=2 and M=10?

Comment: You can still use `multinomial`, and it will be "fair" (by at least one definition of "fair").  Each of the 10 buckets have an equal chance of being assigned one of the two objects.  Of course, that does mean that sometimes both objects will be assigned to the same bucket.  If that is unacceptable, the multinomial distribution won't work for you.